# jQuery attr('id') is returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**html:**

```
<button class="btn" id="1"></button>
<p></p>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $('p').html(id);
});
```

**Returns:**

> undefined

This question is *Corrected*

Comment: can you explain abit about your question

Comment: ty i think `$('p').html(id);` executed before `var id=$(event.target).attr('id');`

Comment: @MedAmine, do you get your answer by [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475518/jquery-attrid-returning-undefined/#48475682)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **`$(this)`**

In this case I suggest you to use `$(this)`

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" id="150">Click Me</button>
```

---

### **`event.target`**

Also as @aspiring_dev mentioned in his answer you can use the **event argument of jQuery handler function** in the `click` function:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(event){
    console.log($(event.target).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="1">Button</button>
<p></p>
```

---

### Different between  `$(this)` and `event.target`

I wrote a click event for div in the following example. now click on the `Button 1` , `Button 2` and yellow `div` to see the different between results. **`event.target` is equal the *child clicked element* but `this` always is equal `div`**.

```js
$('div').click(function(event){
    var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
    var eventTargetId = $(event.target).attr('id');

    console.log('thisId » ' + thisId);

    if(eventTargetId.indexOf('mainDiv')<0)
       console.log('eventTargetId » ' + eventTargetId);
    else
       console.log('eventTargetId' +' = '+ 'thisId » ' + thisId );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv" style="padding:20px;background:#fdd800;border:1px solid orange;">
    <button class="btn1" id="btn1">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn2" id="btn2">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

---

**`window.event.target`**

[image]

[image]

> `event.target` is already available in `IE9+`. If you need to support
>   `IE6-8`, then `event.srcElement` needs to be used.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    console.log($(window.event.target).attr("id"));
    console.log($(window.event.srcElement).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" id="150">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: the code almost like that https://jsfiddle.net/mam8/7qz7n55a/ and i see no problem here i see that problem in localhost

Comment: This code has not any problem. I need more information to help more. If you have a problem with it at local then open browser debugger (ctrl+shift+i) and click the button and look at console tab. It show the error to you and you can update your question with the error then comment on this answer and I can help you again. Also specify your browser and its version in the question.

Comment: TY when I use `$(this)` i dont see the problem again

Comment: @MedAmine, In the most of cases `$(this)` works well. Also I updated my answer and wrote a code that show you different of `$(this)` and `event.target`. Run the examples and see it.

Answer (score 1):

`event` is not defined in the callback, try something like this

```js
$('.btn').click(function(event) { // you're not passing `event` so it's undefined
    var id=$(event.target).attr('id');
    $('p').html(id);
});
```

Comment: Or you could get the target using `$(this)` instead of `$(event.target)`